# Can one study have multiple research questions and hypotheses?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am reading a paper which has a main research question and hypothesis in the introduction. However, it has two subsections for the two experiments it conducts, and for each one, it has multiple hypotheses. Would they count as the hypotheses of the study, or would it be the one mentioned in the introduction?

Comment: Can you edit your question to expand a bit on why the number of hypotheses is important? Knowing the field would be useful too as practice about pre-specifying things differs between fields.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but maybe this is relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem

Comment: Having "multiple working hypotheses" was a key strategy recommended by the geologist T.C. Chamberlin. His papers on the subject have been widely quoted and reprinted in and beyond the Earth sciences.

Comment: @NickCox, yet for the purposes of publishing it could make a sense to pretend that there was only one

Comment: @Aksakal Sure. I am not in favour of pretending as such but you are right.  If the hypothesis is that string theory is valid, and I had a definitive answer, I wouldn't blur the issue. More commonly, too much statistics is already messed up by a false idea that everything must hinge on some null hypothesis test. That seems more common among disciplines using statistics than in statistics in any stricter sense (and as some kind of geographer I see this from several sides).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a primary objective with primary  outcome variables and separate research question. At the same time you could have secondary objectives of the study that could generate its own research questions and measurements, - as long as the secondary does not interfere with the primary objective of the study